# select duplicates in a list linq

Tags: .net, winforms, linq, list

i need to select duplicates from a list using linq and return list of arrays where each of the array contains the duplicates. for example if my list is

```
{2,2,3,13,4,4,15,5,7,8,9,12,13}
```

then i need returned

```
{2,2},{4,4}
```

the following code only returns a single value for each duplicate

```
int[] listOfItems = new[] {2,2,3,13,4,4,15,5,7,8,9,12,13};
var duplicates = listOfItems
    .GroupBy(i => i)
    .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
    .Select(g => g.Key);
foreach (var d in duplicates)
    Console.WriteLine(d);
```

This produces the following:

```
4
2
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well this is the problem:

```
    .Select(g => g.Key)
```

You're explicitly *just* selecting the key.

Remove that call, and you'll select all the groups instead - you'll get an `IEnumerable<IGrouping<int, int>>`. You'll need to change your output as well, of course. For example:

```
foreach (var group in duplicates)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{{{0}}}", group.Join(","));
}
```

EDIT: For a `List<int[]>` you just need:

```
var duplicates = listOfItems
    .GroupBy(i => i)
    .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
    .Select(g => g.ToArray())
    .ToList();
```

Comment: @Smith: No, it will return a sequence of `IGrouping` groups. Will edit to get you a list of arrays...

Answer (score 2):

Just get rid of the `.Select(g => g.Key)` line and you'll have, essentially, nested enumerables.

```
int[] listOfItems = new[] {2,2,3,13,4,4,15,5,7,8,9,12,13};
var duplicates = listOfItems
    .GroupBy(i => i)
    .Where(g => g.Count() > 1);

foreach (var g in duplicateGroups)
{
    foreach (var d in g)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(d); 
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

If you want a list of arrays, you'll want

```
var listOfArrays = duplicates.Select(g => g.ToArray()).ToList();
```

Similarly

```
var listOfLists = duplicates.Select(g => g.ToList()).ToList();
var arrayOfLists = duplicates.Select(g => g.ToArray()).ToList();
var arrayOfArrays = duplicates.Select(g => g.ToArray()).ToArray();
```

Comment: See the update, if you really want a `List` of `[]`s. (`List<int[]>`) However if all you're going to do is `foreach` through them, it doesn't really matter whether it's a list of arrays, or an array of lists, or an `IEnumerable` of `IGrouping`s.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler alternative is this:

```
listOfItems
    .ToLookup(x => x)
    .Where(x => x.Skip(1).Any());
```